# SQL Server : Distinct results

Tags: sql, sql-server, distinct

I have the following SQL Server query

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    e.idetapa, t.idtramo, m.idmunicipio, m.nombre
FROM 
    terapia h, municipios m, tramos t, rutas r, etapas e 
WHERE 
    r.idruta = 15 
    AND h.consume = 's' 
    AND h.idmunicipio = m.idmunicipio 
    AND r.idruta = t.idruta 
    AND e.idruta = r.idruta 
    AND t.idetapa = e.idetapa 
    AND (m.idmunicipio = t.idmuniini OR m.idmunicipio = t.idmunifin)
ORDER BY 
    e.idetapa, t.idtramo
```

This is what I get when executing it:

```
idetapa, idtramo, idmunicipio, nombre
2, 6, 19, Poitiers
2, 7, 19, Poitiers
3, 7, 28, Lyon
3, 8, 28, Lyon
7, 4, 53, Bordeaux
8, 1, 53, Bordeaux
12, 6, 37,Paris
13, 1, 37,Paris
.
.
.
```

I want to modify this query in order to give me UNIQUE idmunicipio and idnombre, ordered by idetapa and idtramo , like this results:

```
19, Poitiers
28, Lyon
53, Bordeaux
37, Paris
```

What can I do? Thanks.

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT idmunicipio, idnombre FROM ... ORDER BY idetapa, idtramo`

Comment: Switch to modern explicit `JOIN` syntax instead! Easier to write (without errors), to read, and to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: I cannot do your select cause when i put an DISTINCT clause, MS SQL says i need to put idetapa and idtramo in SELECT elements too.

Comment: Sorry, it's too early for me. (Need more coffee...) When SELECT DISTINCT, you can only order by selected columns. (Consider case when a idmunicipio has several different idetapa values, how to order?)

Comment: There is logical issue with your request. Since for `19, Poitiers` there are two different values for `idetapa, idtramo` (that is `2, 6` and `2 7`) how is SQL supposed to know according to which pair to sort the results? The requirement to include columns in `SELECT` clause is natural consequence of this requirement. Use grouping and `min`/`max` (or window functions) to tell SQL which of the pairs is more important and sort according to the aggregated results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is logical issue with your request. Since for `19, Poitiers` there are two different values for idetapa, idtramo (that is `2, 6` and `2, 7`) how is SQL supposed to know according to which pair to sort the results? The requirement to include columns in `SELECT` clause is natural consequence of this requirement. Use grouping and `min`/`max` (or window functions) to tell SQL which of the pairs is more important and sort according to the aggregated results. Example:

```
SELECT S.idmunicipio, S.nombre
FROM
(
  SELECT
      max(e.idetapa) as idetapa, max(t.idtramo) as idtramo,
      m.idmunicipio, m.nombre
  FROM 
      terapia h, municipios m, tramos t, rutas r, etapas e 
  WHERE 
      r.idruta = 15 
      AND h.consume = 's' 
      AND h.idmunicipio = m.idmunicipio 
      AND r.idruta = t.idruta 
      AND e.idruta = r.idruta 
      AND t.idetapa = e.idetapa 
      AND (m.idmunicipio = t.idmuniini OR m.idmunicipio = t.idmunifin)
  GROUP BY
      m.idmunicipio, m.nombre
) as S
ORDER BY 
    S.idetapa, S.idtramo
```

Answer (score 1):

Exclude other columns

```
SELECT DISTINCT m.idmunicipio, m.nombre
FROM terapia h, municipios m, tramos t, rutas r, etapas e 
WHERE r.idruta=15 AND h.consume='s' AND h.idmunicipio=m.idmunicipio 
AND r.idruta=t.idruta AND e.idruta=r.idruta AND t.idetapa=e.idetapa 
AND (m.idmunicipio=t.idmuniini OR m.idmunicipio=t.idmunifin)
```

Comment: I need to order by idetapa, idtramo and if order by those 2 fields, i need to put them in the select clause.